# Can Soda Lime glass handle hot liquid? (Like tea, soup, etc.)

Tags: heat, glass

Can [Soda Lime glass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soda-lime_glass) handle storage of hot liquid?

Like tea, soup, hot chocolate, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and No. Soda lime glass is not resistant enough to thermal shock to withstand quick changes in temperature, if you pour boiling liquid into cool soda lime glass it is likely to shatter. If hot glass is suddenly exposed to cold it is also likely to shatter. This means to use soda lime glass with hot liquids you need to gradually warm them close to the temperature if the liquid you are about to put in. Many big temperature changes is likely to weaken the glass, making it less resistant over time.

So can you? Yes, if you are cautious and cushion any large temperature changes, but it is not recommended.